# Powershell Compare Two Strings

Tags: powershell

```
 cls
$logFile = "C:\test\output1.txt"
Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}
LogWrite "DocumentID|Correct|Wrong|UDI|Number of Errors|Line Number"
LogWrite "------------------------------------------"
$file = "C:\test\test\Birth records evt logging.txt"
$pattern = "^(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(COB Reviewed)$"
$pattern2 = "^(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(DocSecID)$"
$pattern3 = "^(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)`t(.*)$"



$errorCountTotal = 0
$linecount = 0
$line2Count = 0
Get-Content $file|

ForEach-Object{
$errorCountLine = 0
$linecount++
$transposition = $false
   if($_ -match $pattern){


    }elseif($_ -match $pattern2){




    }elseif($_ -match $pattern3){
    $line2Count++



            if($matches[6].Length -eq $matches[7].length){
                 $wrong = $matches[6]
                 $correct = $matches[7]
                 $documentID = $matches[3]
                 $UDI = $matches[8]

                $a = [char[]]$Matches[6]
                $b = [char[]]$matches[7]


               # for($i = 0; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++){

                   # for($x = 1; $x -lt $a.Length; $x++){
                       # if($a[$i] -eq $b[$i+$x] -and $a[$i+$x] -eq $b[$i]){
                         #   if($a[$i] -eq $a[$i+$x]){
                           # write-host "same letter"
                         #   }else{

                               # $errorCountLine += 2

                           # }
                       # }

                   # }


                #}





                #Compare-Object $a $b |Format-List |Out-File "C:\test\test3.txt"

                $errorCountLine += (@(Compare-Object $a $b -SyncWindow 0).count /2)

                $errorCountTotal +=$errorCountLine
                Write-Host $matches[6] " - " $matches[7] " - " $errorCountLine " - " $linecount
                Write-Host $errorCountTotal
                LogWrite "$documentID|$wrong|$correct|$UDI|$errorCountLine|$linecount"
            }else{
                $a = [char[]]$Matches[6]
                $b = [char[]]$matches[7]

                for($i = 0; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++){

                    for($x = 1; $x -lt $a.Length; $x++){
                        if($a[$i] -eq $b[$i+$x] -and $a[$i+$x] -eq $b[$i]){
                            if($a[$i] -eq $a[$i+$x]){
                           # write-host "same letter"
                            }else{

                                $errorCountLine += 2

                            }
                        }

                    }


                }

                $diffL = [math]::Abs($Matches[7].Length - $Matches[6].Length)
                $errorCountLine = (((@(Compare-Object $a $b).count-$diffL) /2) + $diffL)
                $test = @(Compare-Object $a $b).count
                $errorCountTotal += $errorCountLine

                Write-Host $matches[6] " - " $matches[7] " - " $errorCountLine " - " $linecount
                $wrong = $matches[6]
                $correct = $matches[7]
                $documentID = $matches[3]
                $UDI = $matches[8]
                LogWrite "$documentID|$wrong|$correct|$UDI|$errorCountLine|$linecount"
                Write-Host $errorCountTotal

            }


    }



}

Write-Host $line2Count #number of lines that the program looks at.  passes through pattern3.
LogWrite `n
LogWrite "The total number of errors is $errorCountTotal"
```

I need to compare the contents of two Strings with this program.  Above is what i have so far.  The only problem is it tells me whether or not the two strings match or not(0 or -1) character by character in the string.  Midred and Mildred would come up as 5 errors when in fact it needs to be only 1 error.  i cannot just compare the strings as a whole either because there could be multiple errors in a string.  any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Compare-Object on the character arrays:

```
$a = [char[]]'Mildred'
$b = [char[]]'Midred'

Compare-Object $a $b


                                                           InputObject SideIndicator                                                        
                                                           ----------- -------------                                                        
                                                                     l <=                   

@(Compare-Object $a $b).count

1
```

Comment: This works for the example i gave but it returns two if there is an incorrect character ex. Hildred and Mildred returns a 2 when really it should also return a 1

Comment: Not sure how it's supposed to know if there's only one.  If one says Sean and the other says Jean, and the name is actually Dean then there really are 2 errors.

Comment: Just did some additional testing, and this might not be a good solution anyway.  It won't catch transposed characters.  You're probably looking at writing a custom function with the exact matching rules you want.

Comment: This wasn't perfect but it got me to where i needed to go.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesn't account for mixed up letters.

Comment: I know. I mentioned earlier that it would not catch transposed characters.

Comment: yea sorry i didn't catch that comment till after i posted and ran the script

Comment: @user3352075: To detect rearranged letters, you can specify a `-SyncWindow` of `0` to [`Compare-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849941.aspx) to have it only compare letters in the same position in each string. (This will output a large number of items if there are missing letters, you might want to run it only if the default compare passes.)

Comment: This works well for transposed characters.  i run it only if the lengths of the two strings are the same.  so if a space takes the place of a character it still works.  it doesn't really work the way i want it to if the strings are uneven lengths but this did get my results that more accurate.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just compare the two strings, e.g.

```
$matches[6] -ne $ matches [7]
```

?

Comment: then it either passes or doesn't pass.  what happens if there are two errors/differences in the strings ex. apdla and apple that would need to count for two errors.